# GET request works, how to make POST work too?

Tags: http, c#-4.0, post, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I have MVC-4 Web-API server, and I need to create HTTP client "by hand" (via TCP) to talk with it.

```
public class UpdateUnitDetailsController : ApiController
{
    // GET api/updateunitdetails
    public IEnumerable<string> Get()
    {
        return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
    }

    // GET api/updateunitdetails/5
    public string Get(int id)
    {
        return "value";
    }

    // POST api/updateunitdetails
    public void Post([FromBody]string value)
    {
    }

    // POST api/updateunitdetails
    public void Post()
    {
    }

    // PUT api/updateunitdetails/5
    public void Put(int id, [FromBody]string value)
    {
    }

    // DELETE api/updateunitdetails/5
    public void Delete(int id)
    {
    }
}
```

I made a simple client and set breakpoints in the server's controller's methods. In the client, I send this:

```
GET /api/updateunitdetails HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:58743

Content-Type: */*
Content-Length: 10

home=sweet
```

And it works (the debugger stops in the `Get` method). But if I change `GET` to `POST`, it doesn't. Moreover, whenever I issue a `POST` request, I see in the Visual Studio Console this message:

`A first chance exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Web.Http.dll`

What do I miss ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this instead:

```
POST /api/updateunitdetails HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:58743

Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded


=sweet
```

Comment: I don't understand. This is `GET`, I'm trying to use `POST`, and where is the `home` in `home=sweet` ? you left only the `=sweet`.. ?

Comment: Sorry I meant POST - and yes, since Web API binds from body, *entire body* needs to be just the value, hence the body hsould be *=sweet*

Comment: What is Content-Type: `*/*` supposed to mean?  I've never seen that before, are you sure it is valid?